# jquery hide/show div based on span text

Tags: jquery

need some help with this. I have a span element where the text changes based on a selection from another drop-down element:

```
<span class="drop link" id="title-tagger-20965969" style="cursor:default;text-decoration:underline;">...ng calls or email - 2E1</span>
```

Basically I want to show the corresponding div ID (as below) that matches the text code on the end of the span element text like the example above (2E1)

```
<div id="changingArea">
<div id="2E1" class="desc">TEXT 2</div>
<div id="2E2" class="desc">TEXT 2</div>
<div id="2E3" class="desc">TEXT 3</div>
</div>
```

I also want all all the 'changingArea' divs hidden unless the span element contains the div id as text.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to share the the code which is changing the text of `title-tagger-20965969` element

Comment: Need to elaborate you question..This one makes no sense..

Comment: please provide your fiddle for this and be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to place the `id` of the div in the `span` `attribute` and hide/show based on the `id`

```
$('span').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('.desc').hide(); //hide all divs
    $('#'+id).show(); //show div based on id
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BapTw/)

**UPDATE**

If you will always have text in the `span` in this format `...ng calls or email - 2E1` where after `-` will be the `id` than you can do it like this

```
$('span').click(function(){
    var html = $(this).html();
    var split = html.split('-');
    $('.desc').hide(); //hide all divs
    $('#'+$.trim(split[1])).show(); //show div based on id
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BapTw/1/)

Comment: Thanks Khawer! I can't edit the span element so this wouldn't work

Comment: Better approach for your first answer http://jsfiddle.net/BapTw/2/ make use of [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: Thanks Tushar i will use this approach from now on :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('span').click(function(){
var txt = $(this).text();
$('.desc').hide(); //hide all divs
var id;
$("div.desc").each(function(){
id=$(this).attr("id");
    if(txt.indexOf(id)>=0){
    $(this).show();
    }
})   
});
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/v3Fuh/1/)